# Using decorators is failing in typeorm

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am new to type ORM, and I'm new to using decorators as well in TypeScript, I am getting an error, I believe it's regarding the `--strictPropertyInitialization` flag set by the typescript rules.

I have no idea how to overcome this problem, what am I doing wrong?

```
import { Entity } from 'typeorm'

@Entity({ name: 'test' })
export class Photo {
  id: number
}
```

```
Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
```

[image]

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@tools/*": ["./tools/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./types/*"],
      "@server/*": ["./server/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["./routes/*"],
      "@models/*": ["./models/*"],
      "@schemas/*": ["./schemas/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["./constants/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["./middlewares/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "declarationDir": "./@types",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "plugins": [{ "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" }]
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "exclude": ["./@types", "node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

What could be the reason to this error?

I read about it [here](https://typescript.tv/errors/#ts2564), but I'm not sure how to solve it

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra, Hi, it's bellow the code snippet, above the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` to the `"compilerOptions"` object of your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict":true, 
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false, 
    // etc.
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to specifying the command line flag

```
tsc -p ./tsconfig.json --strictPropertyInitialization false
```

Note that when we enable [strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), `"strict": true` we enable the whole family of strict checks, that is all compiler options beginning with the term strict. This is usually desirable but in case we need to disable one, we can use the above approach.

Comment: So, whenever we use decorators, we should disable this flag, such as using angular, typeorm or nestjs

Comment: No. Whenever you need to declare non optional properties (`string` vs `string?`) that do not have initializers in the class body. Some prefer to suppress the error woth a `!`

Comment: @Normal I usually leave strictPropertyInitialization enabled in something like angular because i prefer to initialize as many of my properties for various reasons. `MyComponent { total = 0; products: Product[] = []; }` but that's a distant tangent.